# Ingress gateway on each node

Tags: kubernetes, istio

Each node runs the same pods and all the nodes do the same. I am using Istio ingress gateway with the NodePort. I need traffic that enters NodePort to be routed to pods not leaving the node.
I am unable to run `istio-ingressgateway` on each node to do that. Is it possible for each node to route its own traffic?

Bare-metal, k8s 1.19.4, Istio 1.8

Comment: Have You tried adding DestinationRule with sticky session configuration? In istio documentation it can be found on [this](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/destination-rule/#LoadBalancerSettings) page. It's described better [here](https://medium.com/intelligentmachines/istio-part-2-traffic-management-consistent-hashing-canary-dark-releases-38ee0334321a), search for `ConsistentHashing`.

Comment: If `istio-ingressgateway` is running on `node1` then all the traffic that comes to `node2` NodePort will be routed to `node1`? These two nodes are on separate continents and traffic roundtrip would be too slow.

Comment: If they're on seperate continents then [Locality-prioritized load balancing](https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/configuration/traffic-management/locality-load-balancing/#locality-prioritized-load-balancing) should work, so istio should tell Envoy to prioritize traffic to the workload instances most closely matching the locality of the Envoy sending the request. If you are using a hosted Kubernetes service your cloud provider should configure this for you. If you are running your own Kubernetes cluster you will need to add these labels to your nodes.

Comment: Traffic from NodePort goes to istio-ingressgateway-xxxx pod and only then to the rest of the cluster, am I right?

Comment: Yes, every request in istio goes through istio ingress gateway. Then you use gateway, virtual service and destination rule to forward your traffic to specific services.  
Additionally I found an interesting example, take a look at [this](https://www.istiobyexample.dev/locality-load-balancing).

Comment: The problem is that there is just one `istio-ingressgateway` pod on node1 and all the traffic from node2 have to come to node1 . I am trying to change the replica count directly in istio-ingressgateway deployment but it is not changing. Must be some restriction.

Comment: I've tried with `kubectl scale --replicas=3 deployment/istio-ingressgateway -n istio-system` and it scale without any issues, but I'm using loadbalancer instead of a nodeport. What's the issue after you use it? Your node1 is your master and node2 is a worker?

Comment: Great success! :) Previously I have tried to edit deployment and it didn't do anything. Anyway, it did help please answer my question with that scale cmd. Btw currently I test with 1 master and 2 worker nodes. Now I have a gateway running on each worker node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Issue

As @Jonas mentioned in comments

> The problem is that there is just one istio-ingressgateway pod on node1 and all the traffic from node2 have to come to node1

### Solution

You can use [kubectl scale](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#scaling-resources) to scale your ingress gateway replicas. Below command will create 3 ingress gateway pods instead of just one.

```
kubectl scale --replicas=3 deployment/istio-ingressgateway -n istio-system
```

---

Additionally you can set this up with [istio operator](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/istio.operator.v1alpha1/#KubernetesResourcesSpec) replicaCount value.

Note that if you use **cloud** there might be [hpa](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/) configured and it might immediately scales back up the pods. There is github [issue](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/13588) about that. You can also set hpa min and max [replicas](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/istio.operator.v1alpha1/#HorizontalPodAutoscalerSpec) with istio.

Comment: This solution does not ensure that all the wont be distributed all nodes. That's what [K8s Daemons Set](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/) are for.